# Get values by key from Immutable list of maps

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have an Immutable list of maps which have (among other keys) a 'name' key. I am trying to get an array of names.

My list of maps looks like this: `[{'name': 'John', 'age': 23}, {'name': 'Eli', 'age': 30}]`

I have tried doing this:

`var result = myObject.map(function(a) {return a.name;});`

but that's not working. Is not returning an array.

If I do `result.toArray`, I get [`undefined`, `undefined`]

Comment: You need to assign the return value of `map` to some variable.

Comment: See your code is working https://fiddle.jshell.net/bgesk3u6/

Comment: You need not do `result.toArray`. result itself is an array.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] of your issue. @prasad has shown that, so far, your code will work if you assign your object to a variable.

Comment: Map retruns already a  array .Then why again with `toArray`

Comment: I am using Immutable JS, that's why I don't get an array back.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a list of immutable maps, you'll need to use the `get` function to retrieve the name. So the following should work:

```
const list = Immutable.fromJS([{ 'name': 'John', 'age': 23 }, { 'name': 'Eli', 'age': 30 }]);
const result = list.map(a => a.get('name'))); 
console.log(result); // ["John", "Eli"]
```

Accessing the map's values as if it were a regular javascript object will not work:

```
const map = Immutable.Map({ name: 'John', age: 23 });
console.log(map.name) // undefined
console.log(map.get('name')) // John
```

However, assuming all names are fixed, you could use an Immutable Record as follows:

```
const Person = Immutable.Record({ name: '', age: 0 });
const person = new Person({ name: 'John', age: 23 });
console.log(person.name) // John
console.log(person.get('name')) // John
```